# How possible can force open ios app via apple watch

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

Is it possible to launch an application on an iphone via apple watchOS

I want to implement launching an application on an iphone via apple watchOS so that they start at the same time I'm not sure if this is possible, I tried different ways and could not implement it, so the question is whether it is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it is impossible due to iOS security policy.
But with Apple Watch's "shortcuts" I think it'll be possible on a limited basis, depending on what app it is and what you're trying to do with it.
I think you'd better check out "shortcuts".

[shortcuts apple refrerence.](https://%20https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios)